# TinyMCE not showing "hr" in toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, text-editor

I'm trying to use TinyMCE as an editor and want to have the ability to add "hr" elements. I've added the plugin as they outline, but I do not see the "hr" button/option in my editor.

Any insight on this problem would be great!

Here's how I an initiating it:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "template advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview",
        "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
        "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
    ],
    browser_spellcheck : true ,
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | template ",
    menubar: false,
    resize: "both",
    content_css: "/Content/bootstrap.min.css, /Content/Site.css",
    template_cdate_classes: "cdate creationdate",
    template_mdate_classes: "mdate modifieddate",
    template_selected_content_classes: "selcontent",
    template_cdate_format: "%m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S",
    template_mdate_format: "%m/%d/%Y : %H:%M:%S",
    file_browser_callback_types: 'file image media',

    templates: [
        {
            title: "Center Column",
            url: "/Scripts/tinymce/template/center_column.html",
            description: "Adds Editor Name and Staff ID"
        },
        {
            title: "Two Column w/ Image Right",
            url: "/Scripts/tinymce/template/two_column_image_right.html",
            description: "Adds an editing timestamp."
        },
        {
            title: "Two Column w Image Left",
            url: "/Scripts/tinymce/template/two_column_image_left.html",
            description: "Adds an editing timestamp."
        },
        {
            title: "Contact Page",
            url: "/Scripts/tinymce/template/contact_page.html",
            description: "Adds an editing timestamp."
        }
    ]


});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your toollbar syntax should look something like this :

```
toolbar: "hr undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | link image | template ",
```

I inserted the hr button in the beginning of the button stack but you can insert it anywhere you need. Hopefully tinyMCE will write about this on the [relevant page](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/hr/).

Answer (score 0):

Well you did not add `HorizontalRule` to the `toolbar` options.